# サイトが表示できない

Tags: android, monaca, onsen-ui, angular

monacaを使ってwebサイトを表示するアプリを作っているのですが、端末上でアプリを動かすと

> net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

と表示されてしまいmonacaデバッカー上でも

> Refused to display '[http://www.アドレス名.jp/](http://www.%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E5%90%8D.jp/)' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'   
>                                                      www/index.html:0
>   （アドレス名は学校のurlのためここで書くのは控えたいと思います）

とlogが出てきてうまく表示ができません、UIは　Onsen UI V2 Angular 1 Tabbarを使っています。また、web表示部はiframeを使って表示させています。

```
<ons-template id="page1.html">
<ons-page ons-show="item.title = 'Monaca'" ng-controller="page1Controller">
  <iframe frameborder="0" ng-src="http://www.アドレス名.jp" set-iframe></iframe>
</ons-page>
```

自分でもiframeの部分が何か不具合を起こしているということはわかるのですが、まだアプリを作ったことがないのでこの部分をどう書き換えていいのか、また、このiframeを使ったままどのような追記、設定を変更すれば解決するのかがわかりません。完成形は下についている2つのタブをタッチして2つのサイトをタブ部分を表示したまま交互に見られるアプリを作りたいと思っています。

解決策やここをこう直したほうが良いなど教えてください
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

＜状況＞
エラーメッセージ：　” because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' ”
[訳]　だって、'X-Frame-Options'(FrameやiFrameで表示するかどうかのオプション) が 'sameorigin'(同一サイト限定)になってんだもん。
[解説] [http://www.アドレス名.jp/](http://www.%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E5%90%8D.jp/) は、質問のページのサイトとは別のサイトのページですよね。
でも、'X-Frame-Options'で同一サイトじゃないとで表示しないと設定されているので、表示されないのです。

＜解決策＞
[http://www.アドレス名.jp/](http://www.%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E5%90%8D.jp/) を表示できるように設定を変えましょう！

> X-Frame-Options: sameorigin

を

> X-Frame-Options: allow-from [http://www.アドレス名.jp/](http://www.%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E5%90%8D.jp/)

に変えると、
"[http://www.アドレス名.jp/](http://www.%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E5%90%8D.jp/)"のサイトのページはOK という設定になるので表示されるようになるはずです。

試してみてください。

Comment: 状況は、Fumu 7さんの通りだと思うのですが、この「http://www.アドレス名.jp/ 」というサイト自体が、質問者さんが管理しているサイトじゃないのではないでしょうか？ 「http://www.アドレス名.jp/ 」側でX-Frame-Optionsを変更する必要があるわけですが、「http://www.アドレス名.jp/ 」側はセキュリティの問題などでiFrameを禁止しているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 回答、コメントありがとうございます。Fumu7さんの回答からサイト側の設定が必要なことがわかったのですが、KNaitoさんの言うとおりサイトは学校の掲示板で、県が管理しているので設定はこちらから設定できません,,,なんとかアプリ側だけでうまく動かす方法はありませんでしょうか?　よろしくお願いします(_ _)